# Why when we don't assign a zero (0) value of a variable it still appears as value one (1)?

Tags: c

I've been searching around and it comes out that if we don't assign a value of a variable, the output will be undefined. Is that correct and if so, why upon typing on the console: `Hello!` - there are no tabs or blanks but the output is?:

`Blanks: 0`

`Tabs: 1`

`New Lines: 1`

Why `Blanks` isn't `1` as well just like `Tabs` is `1` even when there is obviously no tab ? Is it because we didn't assign any value at the beginning of our code then it can be whatever the compiler decides?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, blanks, tabs, newlines;

    newlines = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {

        if (c == ' '){
            ++blanks;
        }
        else if (c == '\t'){
            ++tabs;
        }
        else if (c == '\n'){
            ++newlines;
        }

        putchar(c);

        if (c == '\n'){
            printf("Blanks: %d\nTabs: %d\nNew Lines: %d\n", blanks, tabs, newlines);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not init. That is the end of any discussion on the values you find.

Comment: What you get as output is irrelevant. Using uninitialized variables causes undefined behavior. If they're not initialized, it doesn't matter what they contain. They may contain `0xDEADBEEF`, which is what you'll be to your job if you don't initialize variables.

Answer (score 0):

Initialized local variables can have any value.

The compiler has no obligation to assign `0` to them. Typically, the value which they get comes from the allocated memory content on the stack. That content is not cleared and given as is when the function is called.

If you want to ensure a specific value, you should initialize your variables.

Answer (score -1):

There are few things. Reading uninitiazlized value is not Undefined behavior always but when the bytes read is a trap respresentation of the type then it is indeed Undefined Behavior otherwise the behavior will be same as if you have used unspecified value. Now here the first time a uninitialized variable will be increased (`somevar++`) - `+1` will be added to the uninitialized garbage value it contained. And in your case it turns out that the uninitialized value is `0` - it is not guaranteed to be `0` every time you do so. It might not be the case when you run it next time. Avoid it. You could have got some garbage values if initial value was not `0`.

So the correct way to write the code will be

```
int blanks = 0, tabs = 0, newlines = 0;
```

Codewise

```
int main(void)
{
    int c, blanks = 0, tabs = 0, newlines = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' '){
            ++blanks;
        }
        else if (c == '\t'){
            ++tabs;
        }
        else if (c == '\n'){
            ++newlines;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("Blanks: %d\nTabs: %d\nNew Lines: %d\n", blanks, tabs, newlines);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a wrong answer. People saw this answer downvoted and they passed by. Did anybody even care to read what is said?